# Point Googlers to new Q&A and redirect them away from outdated Q&A

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think that SO answers are usually better than blog posts, but some questions should stop appearing in google. A lot in PHP or any language has changed. Things we considered good back then, now considered bad, things considered secure, now easy to crack.

I suggest two things:

- If a new question is duplicate for an old, question (define old as you want)
- Write a script that automatically notifies users reading questions from 2012 or older, that the question or answers may be outdated and try to redirect them to newer questions or answers if possible. (if you have another definition for old, then so be it)

I think in Duckduckgo the problem is worse than google, DDG loves SO so much that SO links take the entire first page usually.

Comment: `If the answers to the old question are outdated.` - that may be very difficult to determine.... can you point to some real-life examples of questions with only outdated answers?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i want to avoid giving examples on purpose, I used to give examples and people used to criticize them and ignore the question, I'd prefer to mark all 2012 question as 'potentially outdated' without exception and point to new questions instead, I mean a script that would post links potential alternative newer questions on 2012 questions

Comment: But without examples, it's very hard to make a convincing case that this actually is a problem that needs solving. It's entirely possible that the system mostly works, and old questions with outdated answers usually get new answers, that then usually get voted to the top. I'm not saying that it *is* this way - I wouldn't know, I don't have the numbers - but can you show that the opposite is the case?

Comment: @Lynob [This question was asked before 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php), why would it qualify as being outdated because of its timestamp?

Comment: @Daedalus that's not a terribly representative example to be fair - it's more of a reference document that is being used by folks in the PHP tag every day

Comment: @Pekka웃 see i didnt give any examples, but somehow oldskool gave examples on my  behalf and assume that im thinking something im not thinking about. no need to give examples, you use google everyday, you see what i see,. 1- if you see what i see, no need to give examples coz you know what im talking about, 2- if you don't see what i see then im wrong and you could ignore this question, google anything most are from 2012 or 11, some 13, few 14 and 15. im talking about when the question is posted

Comment: @Pekka웃 I realize it is; however under the OP's defined rules for questions that old, it'd be shown the banner, unless I'm misinterpreting the OP.

Comment: @Daedalus i edited my question to let you define old as you see fit

Comment: @Lynob You can't really complain that others draw conclusions on the limited information you provide; and no, no google search is the same for everyone, due to placement on this globe as well as other factors.  Also, your response doesn't answer my question to you.

Comment: @Daedalus google search doesnt really change when it comes to programming, and it's not my own issue, so this either is seen by everyone and ignored or not seen by anyone and thus my question is irrelevant, I just draw attention to it, perhaps you have other solutions, not the point, the point is that questions as old as 2008 are on top, 2014 or 15 are not coz they are new

Comment: @Lynob Unfortunately, you're wrong there; it changes more than you realize.  People in other countries, or even the same county, have differing searches that cause results to vary.  You cannot state without a doubt that all have the exact same results, every time.

Comment: @Daedalus if you'll continue to think that no such thing as old, and information is reliable, so be it, in 2017 or something, that would be a big problem though, imao, perhaps unsolvable by then

Comment: But it doesn't matter when a question is from - it matters whether its answers are outdated. Surely you can provide examples where that is the case. (I really want to see them - I'm not excluding the possibility that you have a point!)

Comment: @Daedalus i didnt state anything, all im saying is to make sure that newer questions gets on top no matter what country you live in

Comment: @Lynob I gave you an example that would qualify under your auto script rules for old.  Maybe my question up there wasn't clear; in that case, here it is again, in different wording: Why should we display a banner on a question just because of its timestamp?  Timestamp alone cannot be a good judge of how useful something is.  The question I linked is a fine example of that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 http://i.imgur.com/upMf47x.png this just a very basic search, first top 4 are too old, good or not didn't look, and all will be good since this is a basic question but my question is not about quality now, other queries will show worse examples, not on top of my head now, but it's the very nature of google, send the ones that have most hits to the top, and older will most likely have more hits

Comment: But that's an example where [the top-voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1700726/187606) looks like it's still the state of the art. A good example would show a glaring quality problem because of a question's age - it's totally possible that those exist.

Comment: @Lynob If you're not willing to answer the question, at least state so instead of leaving me hanging.  If I missed an answer which addressed the question, please point it out; I've read the comments several times, though I don't see any reply to it.

Comment: @Daedalus i answered it when I said define old as you see fit, if not timestamp then other means, my question is not about the quality of Q or A, my question is the age and so many are aging, i warned today, perhaps a false alarm, perhaps my own bad judgment, but had to notify. for every example there's a counter example, if i give a good example you'll still find better one and we'll never stop, so i prefer not to play that game, a lost game for me by the number of downvotes but i said what i have to say.

Comment: 'There are two kinds of fools: one says, "This is old, therefore it is good"; the other says, "This is new, therefore it is better."' -- [Dean Inge](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/William_Ralph_Inge)

Answer (score 8):

That would be a very bad idea. First of all, you're assuming that newer is better and more desirable. But that is not always the case. Sometimes newer versions of software bring more pain and misery that it's worth for anyone (just like everybody just hated Windows ME (Millenium Edition) back at the time, no one would say that Windows ME is better than Windows 2000 or Windows 98).

Also, sometimes it takes a long time for new versions (for example for PHP) to be become the new standard. For example, PHP 5.6 has been stable for some time now and has new features that it's predecessors didn't have yet. Yet, many people are still running PHP 5.3, 5.4 or 5.5. Some of the "old" questions and answers are still useful to them.

But, let's take it even further and go back to PHP4 -or even PHP3- questions for that matter. Even though the questions and answers may be hopelessly outdated, what if you just got a hoplessly outdated application built in PHP4 shoved into your lap and you need to roll out a quick fix to it (and there is no time/budget to upgrade to PHP5)? People in this scenario would be shut out if we'd start rolling out your suggestions.

Furthermore, every question and answer has a timestamp going with it. Every developer should reasonably know that a question/answer that dates 4 years ago is "prehistoric" in terms of modern day development. But yet those posts may still hold some significant value that is still true today.

So I see no reason to start thinking for people and say "Oh, you're looking for something about this (perhaps outdated) topic? Let us redirect you to something "more relevant". Because whether or not something is relevant and outdated or not is still up for the person looking at the post to decide, not for SO.

Comment: first paragraph, no im not thinking that, and it happens and happens too many times at least for me, 4th paragraph, i know but newer questions are in 3rd or 4th page of google

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that sometimes, questions/answers *don't* age.

For example, the time complexity of a quick sort is not going to change, ever.

Nor is the wisdom of ensuring you can measure something before attempting to optimise it.

Nor the wisdom of not using machine language to develop your accounting package, COBOL to develop your operating system, or Pascal to develop anything. Just kidding :-)

Age may *sometimes* be an indicator that something is dated but, if my questions or answers were somehow flagged just because they were from five years ago, that'd be as much a kick in the guts as my wife leaving me for some 20-year-old pretty boy :-)

Of course, you state that you're free to define "old" in some other way so it may be that you also mean define it in such a way that the age is irrelevant. That wouldn't be *as* bad but you're likely to have all sorts of issues trying to figure out whether a post is obsolete or not, whether it should point to another more recent post.

This may be better left to people's wetware rather than software, since they're far more able to handle the subtleties involved. In other words, give them all the possibilities and let them choose the one most relevant to them.